# How to transfer app documents from Mac to iOS on iTunes 12.7

Tags: ios, itunes, mac, data-transfer, file-transfer

iTunes 12.7 removed the apps section. I've been pushing multi-gigabyte videos from my Mac to my iPad's VLC's application documents folder using iTunes.

How do I transfer app documents from Mac to iOS? (before you ask: AirDrop would be too slow and unreliable for that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, to answer my own question:

It has been renamed to "File Sharing" on the connected device's tab.

I didn't see it on the first try.

Answer (score -2):

You can download iTunes 12.6 from Apple [Here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208079)